# In the AdapTable Context Menu is there a way to change the label text based on the cell value

Tags: ag-grid

We can see that there are functions we can provide for the menu click and also a predicate for whether to show the Menu item. But in our use case we went the text of the Menu Item to change based on the cell value (e.g. if the cell value is Joe Bloggs the menu should read 'Joe Bloggs more info...')

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its fairly straightforward

See:  https://docs.adaptabletools.com/docs/user-interface/context-menu#editing-user-context-menu-entries

You will want something like:

```
adaptableOptions.userFunctions=[
{
    type: 'UserMenuItemLabelFunction',
    name: 'changeMenuLabel',
    handler(menuInfo) {
        // change if Joe Bloggs otherwise return empty string so normal label displayed
       return menuInfo.GridCell.displayValue === 'Joe Bloggs' ? 'Joe Bloggs More Info': ''
    },
}
]
```